# How to use openSSL in command line to encrypt HEX FILE or HEX representation of plaintext?

Tags: encryption, openssl, openssh, php-openssl

I am using OpenSSL in command line to encrypt plaintext using aes encryption.

Following command is used to encrypt the plaintext and produces the ciphertext.

```
openssl enc  -aes-128-ecb -in plaintext_in_char.txt -out plaintext_in_char.txt.enc  -K 5468617473206D79204B756E67204675
```

In the above command , plaintext is given in character format and key is given in hex format.

```
cat plaintext_in_char.txt
Two One Nine Two
```

plaintext_in_char.txt is converted into following hex  by openSSL

```
54776f204f6e65204e696e652054776f
```

before aes operation is performed and this hex value is ex-OR ed with round key 0.

Following files contains hex representation of above plaintext

```
cat plaintext_hex_1.txt
54776f204f6e65204e696e652054776f

cat plaintext_hex_2.txt
0x54776f204f6e65204e696e652054776f


cat plaintext_hex_3.hex
54776f204f6e65204e696e652054776f

cat plaintext_hex_4.hex
0x54776f204f6e65204e696e652054776f
```

I want to pass the hex representation of plaintext as input to encrypt. However, when I try the below commands it not taking input as 
hex input, it is taking them as individual character and converts to hex value again before performing the initial round operation.

```
openssl enc  -aes-128-ecb -in plaintext_hex_1.txt -out plaintext_hex.txt.enc  -K 5468617473206D79204B756E67204675
openssl enc  -aes-128-ecb -in plaintext_hex_2.txt -out plaintext_hex.txt.enc  -K 5468617473206D79204B756E67204675
openssl enc  -aes-128-ecb -in plaintext_hex_3.hex -out plaintext_hex.txt.enc  -K 5468617473206D79204B756E67204675
openssl enc  -aes-128-ecb -in plaintext_hex_2.hex -out plaintext_hex.txt.enc  -K 5468617473206D79204B756E67204675
```

It will be great help if someone can help me to encrypt **hex representation of plaintext** of input data to encrypt using openSSL without further converting into hex value (means preventing hex of hex representation of input).

Is there any other format I need to store the hex representation of plaintext 
to encrypt it as its hex format without further converting hex format again ?

I am using Linux OS.

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with programming.

Comment: may be some bash command helpful.

Answer (score 2):

OpenSSL only accepts input in binary (or base64, optionally). If you want to store the input in hex, however, you could convert it to binary before piping it to openssl in a one-liner, like:

```
cat plain_hex.txt | perl -e 'print pack "H*", <STDIN>' | openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -out plain_hex.txt.enc -K 5468617473206D79204B756E67204675
```

Comment: Thanks mnistic for your answer. Although it is converting hex to ascii(binary) , however the conversion is wrong. I am expecting Two One Nine Two (original plaintext whose hex code I stored in plaintext_hex.txt) , but I am getting one special symbol ? after Two One Nine Two.

Comment: Hex to ascii conversion is required as later openssl will again convert this ascii to hex before Ex-OR operation performed.

Comment: Do you have newline or other white space in your file?

Comment: no, there is no newline or white space. I just run nano plain_hex.txt and then save the file. later I execute cat plain_hex.txt | perl -e 'print pack "H*", <STDIN>'  which produces special symbol at last.

Comment: Nano [adds a newline automatically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13317/how-to-stop-gedit-gvim-vim-nano-from-adding-end-of-file-newline-char). Try running nano with `nano -L plain_hex.txt`

Answer (score 2):

The approach of mnistic is correct. However I was getting one special character at the end of file.

Here I found another alternative command (xxd) to convert the hex code into binary(ascii).

```
cat plain-text_in_hex.txt | xxd -r -ps | openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -out plain_hex.txt.enc -K 5468617473206D79204B756E67204675
```

**xxd command can be used to convert ascii to hex**

```
cat plain-text_in_ascii.txt

Two One Nine Two

xxd -ps plain-text_in_ascii.txt 

54776f204f6e65204e696e652054776f    ----> this is hex representation

we can redirect to a file 

xxd -ps plain-text_in_ascii.txt  > plain-text_in_hex.txt


convert hex to ascii (reverse of previous ascii to hex operation)

xxd -r -ps plain-text_in_hex.txt
```

Hope this helps others.